# Java runtime check

Tags: java, runtime

I want to check what code makes my program run slower or faster, is there a program that can take my code and check what is the runtime? Or are there any other ways to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is a [**profiler**](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+profiler).

Comment: Also, if you end up writing timing code yourself, be sure to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java